# Report Manager asking for credentials

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SysAdmin access. I am able to open some of the report managers of different servers but some are asking for credentials. What is the reason for this and how to fix it.

Like:

http://ServerName1/Reports - Working

http://ServerName2/Reports - Working

http://ServerName3/Reports - Asking for username and Passowrd

Comment: what did you try so far. any error message. are you aware of punctuation.

Comment: When I enter my correct username and password, the prompt reappears again.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that you are having a problem with the data source you deployed to the report server.
Try entering valid credentials for the database which is your data source. Storing it directly in the datasource and then deploying it should also allow you to start the reports like on your other servers.

Answer (score 0):

Standard problem with deployed reports on Report Server is that they have one data source connection string in development environment, but after deploying to server, that data source can become not available.

As you said, you have SysAdmin access on report manager, then you need to check following things:

1. Check Data Source the report is using, maybe the problem lies in fact that your data source is not properly created. Maybe you can test your connection to check connectivity with data source. At same place you can define type of providing credential for data source, so you need to properly set one of offered options ant test the connectivity.
2. Go to report properties in report manager, and check what data source the report is related on. If data source is false, you can easily change it on production at the way you just pick another valid data source.

Comment: I am not opening any report here. Just opening the homepage for the report manager that is http://ServerName3/Reports.